# Make Angular UI accordion fully clickable instead of only Heading Label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I am using an Angular ui-bootstrap accordion. With my current code, I am not able to click and open the entire heading panel, only heading label(Title) is clickable and opening the accordion. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance ! Here is my HTML:

```
 <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <div uib-accordion-group is-open="sv.isOpen" class="panel-default" id="{{ sv.domId }}" heading="{{(sv.type == 'Check Call') && sv.type || sv.type + ': '+ sv.city +', '+sv.state}}" 
    ng-repeat="sv in segment.stopVos" tab-group={{$index+1}}>
       <div class="app-wrapper content">
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of...

```
<uib-accordion-heading>
    Click me
</uib-accordion-heading>
```

Setup you `uib-accordion-heading` to contain a full width element such as `p`, `p` will also provide some default margin so make sure to remove it (or tweak it enough) so it won't mess your style.

```
<uib-accordion-heading>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0;"> Click me </p>
</uib-accordion-heading>
```